# Wordpress inner-section full width

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I want to have a header that will have two inner sections in it both occupying full width of the viewport. I tried many things ( adding custom css to installing many sticky-header plugins ) but nothing's helping.

What I am getting:
[image]

What I want to have:
[image]

Essentially I want my header to be sticky ( by adding all header stuffs in single section and setting the property to be sticky on top). It would be a great help if anybody can find me a way to do this. Maybe not in this procedure but any other.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Section Settings** and set **Columns Gap -> No Gap**

[image]

or set padding 0 from **Advanced** option

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But the problem still persists :( Column gap and  padding will only remove the  inner spacing between the columns but not the spacing around them due to the outer section.